# Proof on $\sup$ of a set and its closure

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

How is it possible to prove this statement?

> Let $g:S \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continous function and $S$ a **open**
>   set. Denoting with $\bar{S}$ the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)#Closure_of_a_set) of $S$, then
>
> $$\sup_{z \in S} |g(z)|=\sup_{z \in \bar{S}} |g(z)|$$

---

If $s=\sup_{z \in \bar{S}} |g(z)|$ then by definition $\forall n \geq 1 \,\,\, \exists  z_n \in \bar{S} : |g(z_n)|>s-\frac{1}{n}.$ But I'm stuck here and I don't know how it is necessary for the function $g$ to be continuous.

Comment: Is $g$ holomrphic?

Comment: The convention is that  $g:S\to T$ means the domain of $g$ is $S,$ and  that $g(x)$  is not defined for $x\not \in S,$  in particular for  $x \in \bar S$ \ $S.$....... What space is $S$ an open subset of? And  what conditions are there  for $g(x)$ when $ x\in \bar S$ \ $S$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let:
$$
A:=\sup_{z\in S}|g(z)|\qquad\text{and}\qquad B:=\sup_{z\in\overline{S}}|g(z)|.
$$
Clearly, $A\leq B$. Now, suppose $z\in \overline{S}$. Choose a sequence $(z_{n})\subset S$ such that $z_{n}\to z$. Since $g$ is continuous, $g(z_{n})\to g(z)$. By definition, $|g(z_{n})|\leq A$ for all $n$. Hence, 
$$
|g(z)|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|g(z_{n})|\leq A.
$$
Since this holds for all $z\in\overline{S}$, it follows that 
$$
B=\sup_{z\in\overline{S}}|g(z)|\leq A.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Is the continuity of $g$ strictly necessary for $\{ |g(z)| \}$ to have the same $\sup$ for $z \in S$ and for $z \in \bar{S}$? That is, could this be shown also in the case that $g$ has discontinuities?

Comment: I'm sure there are cases where the above holds even though $g$ is not continuous everywhere. But, in general, $g$ must be continuous to guarantee that the $\sup$s are the same.