# Question from conway's functional analysis book

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X=\{n^{-1}: n\geq 1\} \cup \{0\}$. Show that $C(X)$ and the space of $c$ are isometrically isomorphic.

Here $c$ is the set of all sequences $\{\alpha_{n}\} \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $\lim \alpha_{n}$ exists.

$C(X)$ is the set of all continuous function on $X$

I need to show that the map from $C(X)$ to $c$ is bijective and preserves the norm. But I'm having difficulties in defining the map. I need help. Thanks in advance.

I started with the map $T:C(X)\rightarrow c$ define $T(f)=\{f(1/n)\}$.
Question:

(1) is my map correct?

(2) if my map is correct then it is easy to show 1-1 and onto but how to show that norm is preserved?

Comment: With the usual topology on $X$ a function $f:X\to\Bbb R$ is continuous iff $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(1/n)=f(0).$

Comment: What are the canonical norms for these spaces again?

Comment: Should be infinity norm I guess

Comment: DanielWainfleet I can understand your point. But still how to show the norm is preserved

Comment: Demophilus I have edited the question with my beginning work

Comment: @MayuranSriskandasingam With respect to "how to show the norm is preserved", use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047283/proof-on-sup-of-a-set-and-its-closure) result.See my answer for details.

Comment: @Pedro Thanks, Pedro.  for the very detailed solution with a lot of respect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take $f\in C(X)$. As $f$ is continuous, $\lim f(n^{-1})$ exists and is equal to $f(0)$.
2. From 1, the map $T:C(X)\to  c$ given by 
   $$T(f)=(f(1),f(2^{-1}), f(3^{-1}),...)$$
   is well-defined.
3. It is clear that $T$ is linear.
4. Suppose $T(f)=0$. Then $f(1)=f(2^{-1})=\cdots=0$ and thus (by 1) $f(0)=0$. So, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$, i.e., $f=0$. From 3, we conclude that $T$ is injective.
5. Take $\{\alpha_n\}_1^\infty$ in $c$. Then, $\alpha:=\lim \alpha_n$ exists. Define $f:X\to \mathbb F$ by $f(0)=\alpha$ and $f(n^{-1})=\alpha_n$ for $n>0$. Then, $\lim f(n^{-1})=f(0)$ and thus $f\in C(X)$ (because $0$ is the unique "non trivial" limit point of $X$). In addition, $Tf=\{\alpha_n\}_1^\infty$. This shows that $T$ is surjective.
6. Note that
   \begin{align*}
   \|Tf\|_{c}&=\|(f(1),f(2^{-1}), f(3^{-1}),...)\|_{c}\\\\
   &=\sup_{x\in\{n^{-1}\mid n\geq 1\} } \|f(x)\|_{\mathbb F}\\\\
   &=\sup_{x\in\overline{\{n^{-1}\mid n\geq 1\}} } \|f(x)\|_{\mathbb F}\quad\text{(because $f$ is continuous)}\\\\
   &=\sup_{x\in X} \|f(x)\|_{\mathbb F}\\\\
   &=\|f\|_{C(X)}
   \end{align*}
   and thus $T$ is an isometry.

Comment: Thanks, Pedro.  for the very detailed solution with a lot of respect